# consequences of the periodicity of a function $f(t, x)$ for the accompanying differential equation $\dot{x} = f(t, x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a (continuous) function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that is $p$-periodic in the first variable, meaning that $f(t + p, x) = f(t, x)$ for all $t, x \in \mathbb{R}$, with p > 0.

First, I want to find out what consequences this does have for the slope field of the differential equation $\dot{x} = f(t, x)$. Based on that, I want to make an educated assumption about what this indicates about the solution of the differential equation $\dot{x}(t) = f(t, x(t))$, and want to verify (or discard) this assumption.

To the first part: the slope field consists of vectors of the shape $\pmatrix{1 \\ f(t, x)}$ being placed at the point $(t, x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, in case that $f(t + p, x) = f(t, x)$, we have that $\pmatrix{1 \\ f(t + p, x)} = \pmatrix{1 \\ f(t, x)}$ for all $x, t \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, the slope field is $p$-periodic along the $t$-axis. So far, so good.

But with the second part, I've had trouble so far. My first guess was that the solutions would have to be $p$-periodic, but I've quickly come to the conclusion that this assumption doesn't hold: if we consider the function $f(t, x) = x - sin(t)$, altogether with the differential equation $\dot{x}(t) = x(t) - sin(t)$, then the solutions of this equation have the shape $x(t) = c e^t + \frac{sin(t)}{2} + \frac{cos(t)}{2}, c \in \mathbb{R}$ (according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28t%29%20%3D%20y%28t%29-sin%28t%29)), which aren't periodic (unless $c = 0$). Therefore, this guess about the periodicity is apparently wrong.

My second guess would be that if there's a solution $x_1: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$, that we could conclude the existence of another solution $x_2: (a + p, b + p) \to \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto x_1(t - p)$ or something along that lines. But this guess seems to be wrong aswell, if we again consider the counterexample $f(t, x) = x - sin(t)$.

Therefore, I'm rather confused on what exactly I am to "guess" and to verify about the solution. What exactly *can* we deduce about the solution of the differential equation, based on the periodicity of the slope field or of $f$? Is there something totally obvious that I'm missing? Or is there anything wrong about my counterexamples?

Comment: In your differential equation the periodicity is lost since now $f=f(t,x(t))$ where the arguments are no longer independent variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something you can say: if $x(t)$ is a solution, so is $x(t+p)$. I do not think that anything more can be said in the general case. For particular cases you might be able to say something. For example consider the case $f(t,x)=P(t)\,g(x)$, where $P$ is periodic and $\int_0^pP(t)\,dt=0$.

Comment: That's what I was missing. I somehow didn't realize that, given a solution $x(t)$, $x(t + p)$ is a solution aswell (which is what the task probably wanted me to figure out), but was just thinking too much about in which cases a solution might be periodic. Thanks.